Jolt to transform a multilayered Nested JSON to flat JSON
Input
{
  "CustomerMaster": {
    "Rootnode": {
      "KUNNR": "0000000199",
      "NAME1": "COOP Sverige AB",
      "LAND1": "SE",
      "SalesArea": [
        {
          "VKORG": "1301",
          "VTWEG": "00",
          "SPART": "00",
          "PartnerFunction": [
            {
              "PARVW": "WE",
              "PARZA": "000",
              "KUNN2": "0000000199"
            },
            {
              "PARVW": "YP",
              "PARZA": "000",
              "KUNN2": "0087000579"
            },
            {
              "PARVW": "AG",
              "PARZA": "000",
              "KUNN2": "0000000199"
            },
            {
              "PARVW": "RE",
              "PARZA": "000",
              "KUNN2": "0000000199"
            },
            {
              "PARVW": "RG",
              "PARZA": "000",
              "KUNN2": "0000000199"
            },
            {
              "PARVW": "ZP",
              "PARZA": "000",
              "KUNN2": "0000000199"
            },
            {
              "PARVW": "Z0",
              "PARZA": "000",
              "KUNN2": "0000078178"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "VKORG": "1301",
          "VTWEG": "10",
          "SPART": "00",
          "Indicator": {
            "IsPlanAccount": "X",
            "IsDistributionCenter": "X"
          },
          "PartnerFunction": [
            {
              "PARVW": "YP",
              "PARZA": "000",
              "KUNN2": "0087000579"
            },
            {
              "PARVW": "WE",
              "PARZA": "000",
              "KUNN2": "0000000199"
            },
            {
              "PARVW": "AG",
              "PARZA": "000",
              "KUNN2": "0000000199"
            },
            {
              "PARVW": "ZP",
              "PARZA": "000",
              "KUNN2": "0000000199"
            },
            {
              "PARVW": "RG",
              "PARZA": "000",
              "KUNN2": "0000000199"
            },
            {
              "PARVW": "RE",
              "PARZA": "000",
              "KUNN2": "0000000199"
            },
            {
              "PARVW": "Z0",
              "PARZA": "000",
              "KUNN2": "0000078178"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "VKORG": "1330",
          "VTWEG": "00",
          "SPART": "00",
          "PartnerFunction": [
            {
              "PARVW": "ZP",
              "PARZA": "000",
              "KUNN2": "0090000100"
            },
            {
              "PARVW": "WE",
              "PARZA": "000",
              "KUNN2": "0000000199"
            },
            {
              "PARVW": "AG",
              "PARZA": "000",
              "KUNN2": "0000000199"
            },
            {
              "PARVW": "RG",
              "PARZA": "000",
              "KUNN2": "0000000199"
            },
            {
              "PARVW": "RE",
              "PARZA": "000",
              "KUNN2": "0000000199"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Expected Output:
[ {
  "KUNNR" : "0000000199",
  "NAME1" : "COOP Sverige AB",
  "LAND1" : "SE",
  "VKORG" : "1301",
  "VTWEG" : "00",
  "SPART" : "00",
  "PARVW" : "WE",
  "PARZA" : "000",
  "KUNN2" : "0000000199"
}, {
  "KUNNR" : "0000000199",
  "NAME1" : "COOP Sverige AB",
  "LAND1" : "SE",
  "VKORG" : "1301",
  "VTWEG" : "00",
  "SPART" : "00",
  "PARVW" : "YP",
  "PARZA" : "000",
  "KUNN2" : "0087000579"
}, {
  "KUNNR" : "0000000199",
  "NAME1" : "COOP Sverige AB",
  "LAND1" : "SE",
  "VKORG" : "1301",
  "VTWEG" : "00",
  "SPART" : "00",
  "PARVW" : "AG",
  "PARZA" : "000",
  "KUNN2" : "0000000199"
}, {
  "KUNNR" : "0000000199",
  "NAME1" : "COOP Sverige AB",
  "LAND1" : "SE",
  "VKORG" : "1301",
  "VTWEG" : "00",
  "SPART" : "00",
  "PARVW" : "RE",
  "PARZA" : "000",
  "KUNN2" : "0000000199"
}, {
  "KUNNR" : "0000000199",
  "NAME1" : "COOP Sverige AB",
  "LAND1" : "SE",
  "VKORG" : "1301",
  "VTWEG" : "00",
  "SPART" : "00",
  "PARVW" : "RG",
  "PARZA" : "000",
  "KUNN2" : "0000000199"
}, {
  "KUNNR" : "0000000199",
  "NAME1" : "COOP Sverige AB",
  "LAND1" : "SE",
  "VKORG" : "1301",
  "VTWEG" : "00",
  "SPART" : "00",
  "PARVW" : "ZP",
  "PARZA" : "000",
  "KUNN2" : "0000000199"
}, {
  "KUNNR" : "0000000199",
  "NAME1" : "COOP Sverige AB",
  "LAND1" : "SE",
  "VKORG" : "1301",
  "VTWEG" : "00",
  "SPART" : "00",
  "PARVW" : "Z0",
  "PARZA" : "000",
  "KUNN2" : "0000078178"
}, {
  "KUNNR" : "0000000199",
  "NAME1" : "COOP Sverige AB",
  "LAND1" : "SE",
  "VKORG" : "1301",
  "VTWEG" : "10",
  "SPART" : "00",
  "IsPlanAccount" : "X",
  "IsDistributionCenter" : "X",
  "PARVW" : "YP",
  "PARZA" : "000",
  "KUNN2" : "0087000579"
}, {
  "KUNNR" : "0000000199",
  "NAME1" : "COOP Sverige AB",
  "LAND1" : "SE",
  "VKORG" : "1301",
  "VTWEG" : "10",
  "SPART" : "00",
  "IsPlanAccount" : "X",
  "IsDistributionCenter" : "X",
  "PARVW" : "WE",
  "PARZA" : "000",
  "KUNN2" : "0000000199"
}, {
  "KUNNR" : "0000000199",
  "NAME1" : "COOP Sverige AB",
  "LAND1" : "SE",
  "VKORG" : "1301",
  "VTWEG" : "10",
  "SPART" : "00",
  "IsPlanAccount" : "X",
  "IsDistributionCenter" : "X",
  "PARVW" : "AG",
  "PARZA" : "000",
  "KUNN2" : "0000000199"
}, {
  "KUNNR" : "0000000199",
  "NAME1" : "COOP Sverige AB",
  "LAND1" : "SE",
  "VKORG" : "1301",
  "VTWEG" : "10",
  "SPART" : "00",
  "IsPlanAccount" : "X",
  "IsDistributionCenter" : "X",
  "PARVW" : "ZP",
  "PARZA" : "000",
  "KUNN2" : "0000000199"
}, {
  "KUNNR" : "0000000199",
  "NAME1" : "COOP Sverige AB",
  "LAND1" : "SE",
  "VKORG" : "1301",
  "VTWEG" : "10",
  "SPART" : "00",
  "IsPlanAccount" : "X",
  "IsDistributionCenter" : "X",
  "PARVW" : "RG",
  "PARZA" : "000",
  "KUNN2" : "0000000199"
}, {
  "KUNNR" : "0000000199",
  "NAME1" : "COOP Sverige AB",
  "LAND1" : "SE",
  "VKORG" : "1301",
  "VTWEG" : "10",
  "SPART" : "00",
  "IsPlanAccount" : "X",
  "IsDistributionCenter" : "X",
  "PARVW" : "RE",
  "PARZA" : "000",
  "KUNN2" : "0000000199"
}, {
  "KUNNR" : "0000000199",
  "NAME1" : "COOP Sverige AB",
  "LAND1" : "SE",
  "VKORG" : "1301",
  "VTWEG" : "10",
  "SPART" : "00",
  "IsPlanAccount" : "X",
  "IsDistributionCenter" : "X",
  "PARVW" : "Z0",
  "PARZA" : "000",
  "KUNN2" : "0000078178"
}, {
  "KUNNR" : "0000000199",
  "NAME1" : "COOP Sverige AB",
  "LAND1" : "SE",
  "VKORG" : "1330",
  "VTWEG" : "00",
  "SPART" : "00",
  "PARVW" : "ZP",
  "PARZA" : "000",
  "KUNN2" : "0090000100"
}, {
  "KUNNR" : "0000000199",
  "NAME1" : "COOP Sverige AB",
  "LAND1" : "SE",
  "VKORG" : "1330",
  "VTWEG" : "00",
  "SPART" : "00",
  "PARVW" : "WE",
  "PARZA" : "000",
  "KUNN2" : "0000000199"
}, {
  "KUNNR" : "0000000199",
  "NAME1" : "COOP Sverige AB",
  "LAND1" : "SE",
  "VKORG" : "1330",
  "VTWEG" : "00",
  "SPART" : "00",
  "PARVW" : "AG",
  "PARZA" : "000",
  "KUNN2" : "0000000199"
}, {
  "KUNNR" : "0000000199",
  "NAME1" : "COOP Sverige AB",
  "LAND1" : "SE",
  "VKORG" : "1330",
  "VTWEG" : "00",
  "SPART" : "00",
  "PARVW" : "RG",
  "PARZA" : "000",
  "KUNN2" : "0000000199"
}, {
  "KUNNR" : "0000000199",
  "NAME1" : "COOP Sverige AB",
  "LAND1" : "SE",
  "VKORG" : "1330",
  "VTWEG" : "00",
  "SPART" : "00",
  "PARVW" : "RE",
  "PARZA" : "000",
  "KUNN2" : "0000000199"
} ]

I'm trying to write a spec to do the below transformation using jolt transformation. I need to convert the flat json to nested Json
I am having some trouble with converting the flat JSON to Nested JSON. I have looked at examples and didn't get any closer as to what is mentioned above. I need to transform a JSON structure by using a JOLT spec. I use https://jolt-demo.appspot.com to test the following below.

Unlikely seems you need to flatten

@BarbarosÖzhan I have to insert this JSON in to a Database table, so flattening is required to convert the data in record format.

You can nest outermost objects into common objects such as else1 and else2 within the first shift transformation spec, and then accumulate within the second one as in the below case :
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "CustomerMaster": {
        "Rootnode": {
          "*": "else1.&",
          "SalesArea": {
            "*": {
              "*": "&1.else2.&",
              "PartnerFunction": {
                "*": {
                  "*": "&3.&2[&1].&"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "PartnerFunction": {
          "*": {
            "@3,else1": { "*": "&4[&1].&" },
            "@2,else2": { "*": "&4[&1].&" },
            "*": "&3[&1].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { //get rid of the outermost keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]


Hi @JasonMoore can you please add to this question what else(  extra cases )  you need to the bottom after the title Edit :

Hi @Barbaros Ozhan , I have updated the question now.
